# How to replace lambda in OrderBy by local method

Tags: c#

I have a function which returns (depends on passed condition) proper function:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<DataRow> SortInDirection(IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, Func<DataRow, string> func, SortType direction)
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case SortType.Ascending when rows is IOrderedEnumerable<DataRow> ordered:
                    return ordered.ThenBy(func);
                case SortType.Ascending:
                    return rows.OrderBy(func);
                case SortType.Descending when rows is IOrderedEnumerable<DataRow> ordered:
                    return ordered.ThenByDescending(func);
                case SortType.Descending:
                    return rows.OrderByDescending(func);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
```

Invoke in method looks like:

```
string SortSelector(DataRow _) => first.ColumnName;

var sorted = SortInDirection(table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), SortSelector, first.SortType);
```

But it doesn't work properly. It indicated that this local method `string SortSelector` is bad. I need to do

```
OrderBy(x=>x.ColumnName)
```

(or OrderByDescending), or ThenBy etc. - depends)
Thanks in advance

Comment: does `_ => SortSelector(_)` work? (note: this wouldn't really be an improvement over just using `_ => first.ColumnName`)

Comment: How can I invoke it or pass? Sorry, but i am very very new in functional programming

Comment: The func, is not set up as an expression, so I am assuming you simply want to sort by the value itself? Yet the call returns a column name.  From what I can read now, if you order by first.columnname for each row, no actual sorting would take place.

Comment: That's it. Sorting is doesn't work. It returns is same order as I passed.

Comment: ```
 string SortSelector(DataRow _) => SortSelector(_);
            var sorted = SortInDirection(table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), SortSelector, first.SortType);
```
Still doesn't work :/

Comment: Ah, then you need either an implementation that dynamically gets the value based on the columnname, or a strongly typed one that returns the value. Seeing you are using datarow (the standard system.data.datarow? ), You can create a helper function inside `SortInDirection` that returns the actual value.
Then again, you might want to use an expression instead of something that returns the columnname, unless you actually want to extract the value from DataRow itself.
Hmm, this might be a lot to take in. Does it make any sense?

Comment: How to do it in simply way but still on lambdas?

Comment: Do you need lambdas though, if I may ask: do you ever return a different column name for each separate datarow? If you have a single column to sort on for the entire set, you might as well pass a string (`first.columnname` ) or use `nameof` depending on the circumstances.
In this case, leaving the code as is, you should be able to use `string SortSelector(DataRow row) => row[first.ColumnName] as string;` (not the most optimal of course, and the *value* of the column has to be a string)

Comment: @Me.Name - could you rewrite your comment as a answer? I will accept it and will give you thumb up ;)

Comment: ```
string SortSelector(DataRow row) => row[first.ColumnName].ToString();

            var sorted = SortInDirection(table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), _ => SortSelector(_), first.SortType);
            
            foreach (var level in _config.Conditions.Skip(1))
            {
                string SortSel(DataRow row) => row[level.ColumnName].ToString();
                sorted = SortInDirection(sorted, _ => SortSel(_), level.SortType);
            }
```
In this case (in foreach) it doesn't sort again.